# Не создается представление в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не получается создать представление в PostgreSQL. Задача стоит так: "Ведомость на получение зарплаты" (оклад-13%). Если есть несовершеннолетние дети, одна минимальная зарплата налогом не облагается. Есть 3 таблицы: работники, их дети, профессии. Вот, что у меня вышло, что требуется поправить, чтобы запрос стал корректным?

```
CREATE VIEW salaries as select emp.fio, 
(select (case 
        when DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE) - DATE_PART('year', child.birtdate)>=18
            then prof.salary=prof.salary*0.87
        else prof.salary
    end) as worker_salary
 from child,emp,prof where child.tabno=emp.tabno and emp.profn=prof.name) 
from emp order by emp.fio
```

Comment: если в таблице child более одной записи для одного сотрудника, то у вас на выходе будет так же несколько записей на одного сотрудника, что, видимо, не верно. А если у сотрудника нет детей, то ваш запрос вообще не покажет его. Что такое "одна минимальная зарплата", какой ее размер или откуда ее брать ? Может ли зарплата быть меньше минимальной ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW salaries AS
SELECT работник,
       CASE WHEN (год_сегодня - MAX(год_рождения_ребёнка)) < 18 -- считать по младшему ребёнку
            THEN минимальная_зарплата + (зарплата - минимальная_зарплата) * 0.87
            ELSE зарплата * 0.87
            END AS зарплата_с_вычетом
FROM работники, дети, профессии
WHERE условия связывания таблиц
GROUP BY работник
```